# Make Json Model for API Call Xml2Json

Tags: json, xml, flutter, api, dart

I am calling an Api that returns data in `XMl`

I then convert it from `XML` to `Json` using  `Xml2Json`, to then decode and acheive a `JsonMap`, which is returning a map well.

When I then go to do `locations.fromJson` to be able to call data from my model is is returning as `null`.

I guess converting from XML may complicate but I have tried all possibilities, parsing the entire response, the section I need and modifying the model in all the ways I could.

The data is returning fine as `Json`, but there is just some disconnect when parsing it with my model, made via quicktype.io

When I call it in any way, be it `print` or a data retrieval, it returns on  `null` at `vehicleActivity`

The call

```
Future<Locations> fetchLiveLocations() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var locations;
    Xml2Json xml2Json = new Xml2Json(); 

    
 try{
    var response = await client.get(
    'https_call');    
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    xml2Json.parse(response.body);
    var jsonString = xml2Json.toGData();
    var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
    //jsonMap is returning fine

    locations = Locations.fromJson(jsonMap);
    //Returning as null

  }
 } catch(Exception) {
  return locations;
 }

  return locations;
 }
```

Top part of Json Model

```
import 'dart:convert';

Locations locationsFromJson(String str) => Locations.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String locationsToJson(Locations data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Locations {
    Locations({
        this.vehicleActivity,
    });

    List<VehicleActivity> vehicleActivity;

    factory Locations.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Locations(
        vehicleActivity: List<VehicleActivity>.from(json["VehicleActivity"].map((x) => VehicleActivity.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "VehicleActivity": List<dynamic>.from(vehicleActivity.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class VehicleActivity {
    VehicleActivity({
        this.recordedAtTime,
        this.itemIdentifier,
        this.validUntilTime,
        this.monitoredVehicleJourney,
        this.extensions,
    });

    DateTime recordedAtTime;
    String itemIdentifier;
    DateTime validUntilTime;
    MonitoredVehicleJourney monitoredVehicleJourney;
    Extensions extensions;

    factory VehicleActivity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VehicleActivity(
        recordedAtTime: DateTime.parse(json["RecordedAtTime"]),
        itemIdentifier: json["ItemIdentifier"],
        validUntilTime: DateTime.parse(json["ValidUntilTime"]),
        monitoredVehicleJourney: MonitoredVehicleJourney.fromJson(json["MonitoredVehicleJourney"]),
        extensions: Extensions.fromJson(json["Extensions"]),
    );
```

XML File Returned

```
<Siri xmlns="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri http://www.siri.org.uk/schema/2.0/xsd/siri.xsd" version="2.0">
<ServiceDelivery>
<ResponseTimestamp>2021-12-03T18:11:05.408806+00:00</ResponseTimestamp>
<ProducerRef>ItoWorld</ProducerRef>
<VehicleMonitoringDelivery>
<ResponseTimestamp>2021-12-03T18:11:05.408806+00:00</ResponseTimestamp>
<RequestMessageRef>5747b24f</RequestMessageRef>
<ValidUntil>2021-12-03T18:16:05.408806+00:00</ValidUntil>
<ShortestPossibleCycle>PT5S</ShortestPossibleCycle>

<VehicleActivity>
<RecordedAtTime>2021-12-03T18:10:01+00:00</RecordedAtTime>
<ItemIdentifier>ad2c7031-ceac-4e7c-bc0c-9e667ad00dfe</ItemIdentifier>
<ValidUntilTime>2021-12-03T18:16:05.408968</ValidUntilTime>
<MonitoredVehicleJourney>
<LineRef>4</LineRef>
<DirectionRef>inbound</DirectionRef>
<FramedVehicleJourneyRef>
<DataFrameRef>2021-12-03</DataFrameRef>
<DatedVehicleJourneyRef>4_20211203_18_04</DatedVehicleJourneyRef>
</FramedVehicleJourneyRef>
<PublishedLineName>4</PublishedLineName>
<OperatorRef>FTVA</OperatorRef>
<DestinationRef>03700324</DestinationRef>
<VehicleLocation>
<Longitude>-0.719601</Longitude>
<Latitude>51.520305</Latitude>
</VehicleLocation>
<Bearing>30.0</Bearing>
<BlockRef>801312</BlockRef>
<VehicleRef>69921</VehicleRef>
</MonitoredVehicleJourney>
<Extensions>
<VehicleJourney>
<Operational>
<TicketMachine>
<TicketMachineServiceCode>B4</TicketMachineServiceCode>
<JourneyCode>1815</JourneyCode>
</TicketMachine>
</Operational>
<VehicleUniqueId>69921</VehicleUniqueId>
<DriverRef>801312</DriverRef>
</VehicleJourney>
</Extensions>
</VehicleActivity>
```

Comment: Firstly, it seems easier to just use the capabilities in the `xml` package to parse the XML directly into any classes (or simpler maps and lists) that you need - rather than going via JSON. Are you sure you aren't throwing an exception and falling into the cath that just returns a null? Add `print` statements.

Comment: @RichardHeap Thanks for your response. First off, I think I have came to that conclusion too, to keep it in ```Xml```. Secondly, I have been using ```Print``` statements and it is throwing the ```null``` @ ```vehicleActivity```. What I want to extract is a ```Lat,Long``` for each example in the list

Comment: add a snippet of the XML file

Comment: @RichardHeap Apologies, thought I had included one - have inserted one now. There is ```Siri``` prefix text and then the ```xml``` data is in the tree ```</VehicleActivity>``` to ```</VehicleActivity>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example `VehicleActivity` class - note that it doesn't handle any errors like missing XML tags or unparsable dates, which you should add yourself.

```
class VehicleActivity {
  VehicleActivity({
    this.recordedAtTime,
    this.itemIdentifier,
    this.validUntilTime,
  });

  DateTime? recordedAtTime;
  String? itemIdentifier;
  DateTime? validUntilTime;

  factory VehicleActivity.fromElement(XmlElement vaElement) => VehicleActivity(
        recordedAtTime: DateTime.parse(
          vaElement.findElements('RecordedAtTime').first.text,
        ),
        itemIdentifier: vaElement.findElements('ItemIdentifier').first.text,
        validUntilTime: DateTime.parse(
          vaElement.findElements('ValidUntilTime').first.text,
        ),
      );
}
```

You would use the factory method from the enclosing tag (similar to how your JSON parsers are written), for each of the vehicle activity tags it finds. (Note that XML can have multiple identically named tags, which is why the code is using `first` to find the (hopefully) one and only tag. If you want to parse XML correctly you need to deal with this - and note that the trip through JSON could break this - but not with your simple schema.)

Here's a simple example that just finds all the vehicle activity tags:

```
  final doc = XmlDocument.parse(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
  final allActivities = doc
      .findAllElements('VehicleActivity')
      .map((e) => VehicleActivity.fromElement(e))
      .toList();
  print(allActivities);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. First question where does the model class situate? Shall I have it in separate ```.dart``` file like my Json model was? And 2, how does the revised ```xml``` call fit into my Https call, do I place it just after the call within the ```fetch``` method, where ```xml2json``` parse is?

Comment: How you structure your code is up to you, but it makes sense to keep your model classes separate. Yes, replace reading the file with `response.body` or `utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)` - I updated the answer to show this.

Comment: I receive the error ```type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<VehicleActivity>'``` at the bottom of the call. I have tried to adapt code but no luck

Comment: API is not returning ```null```, i receive an instance

Comment: Please provide more details: where do you get the error, what `print` lines have you added to help debug, where are you returning a `FutureOr`  (there isn't one in my code above). Feels like you should accept this answer if helpful and pose a new question if the problem has changed.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have managed to fix. I will accept answer now. One question, to make an XML class, is there an automated service like Quicktype for Json parsing? I am unable to find one.

Comment: I'm not aware of one.